# What is best way to deny creation of public S3 buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to deny creation of public S3 buckets from the organization  level?

Can I use Service Control policy to achieve  this?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Give it a try and let us know how it went. Can I ask... why do you wish to prevent an account from being able to create S3 buckets? I'm a little worried that some services (eg CloudFormation) that use S3 _might_ no longer function, so I would recommend some testing of the impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could  try`Deny` modifications to Bucket and/or Account [Public Access Blocks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html) in S3:

- [s3:PutBucketPublicAccessBlock](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_control_PutPublicAccessBlock.html) - Grants permission to create or modify the PublicAccessBlock configuration for an AWS account
- [s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutPublicAccessBlock.html) - Grants permission to create or modify the PublicAccessBlock configuration for a specific Amazon S3 bucket)

This is special S3 features that will restrict creating any bucket policies or ACLs which would make your your bucket or objects [public](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html#access-control-block-public-access-policy-status)

You could also consider setting an automation based on [AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/WhatIsConfig.html). If you enable it, you can define a number of rules that can **monitor your SGs**. The rules can be custom or AWS managed. In fact AWS provides two managed rules that could be useful to you:

- [s3-bucket-public-read-prohibited](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-public-read-prohibited.html)
- [s3-bucket-public-write-prohibited](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-public-write-prohibited.html)

The rules would continuously (or periodically if you prefer that) scan for bucket configuration changes. If any bucket is found non-complaint you could **remediate the issue automatically** using SSM Automation or AWS Lambda function.